# Macro with changing values

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

How do I run a macro every time a certain cell changes its value?  I am running a Macro and using the =RANDBETWEEN function to generate a lot of numbers using a macro. Thanks!

Comment: as GSerg suggests, you need to check ANY change to the worksheet, triggering a check to see whether the specific address is changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Change` Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220862%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address(False, False, xlA1) = "A1" Then
    '...
  End If
End Sub
```